# Does react native supports Mac os version 10.11.6

Tags: xcode8, react-native-ios

HI I have mac mini on which I have 10.11.6 installed I am unable to update mac os to 10.13. so wanted to use react native on this version can any one help me out

Thanks in advance

Comment: If your question is can you develop react native apps on 10.11.6 then yes you can

Comment: @NemiShah Thanks for so quick reply , My concern is can I use latest version of react native and which version of xcode  should I use because I am unable to get the working xcode for mac 10.11.6